# Distributing time in interval buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic, generate-series

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE f_contact (
    agent character varying,
    datetimeconnect timestamp without time zone,
    datetimedisconnect timestamp without time zone,
    duration integer
);
```

`duration` is time in seconds between the disconnect time and connect time.
I might have data like this:

```
agent   datetimeconnect         datetimedisconnect      duration
20024   2019-03-18 12:01:00.0   2019-03-18 13:01:30.0   3630
20011   2019-03-11 08:47:40.0   2019-03-11 09:30:10.0   2550
```

And I want to take that data and distribute the time over 15 minute intervals so I have a result like this:

```
20024   12:00   840
20024   12:15   900
20024   12:30   900
20024   12:45   900 
20024   13:00   90
20011   08:45   740
20011   09:00   900
20011   09:15   900
20011   09:30   10
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting problem.  I slightly simplified the column naming to do:

```
with t as (
      select 20024 as agent, '2019-03-18 12:01:00.0'::timestamp as conn, '2019-03-18 13:01:30.0'::timestamp as disconn, 3630 duration union all
      select 20011, '2019-03-11 08:47:40.0', '2019-03-11 09:30:10.0', 2550
     )
select gs.t, t.*,
       extract(epoch from least(gs.t + interval '15 minute', disconn) - greatest(gs.t, conn))
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(date_trunc('hour', t.conn), date_trunc('hour', t.disconn) + interval '1 hour', interval '15 minute') gs(t)
where conn <= gs.t + interval '15 minute' and disconn >= gs.t ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=67449aac983c5753e5b828412bb1568b) is a db<>fiddle.

What I realize is that the duration column is unnecessary.  You are trying the capture the seconds of overlap with 15 minute intervals.

This creates intervals on the hour boundaries -- this is just easier.  That means that some of the overlaps are not correct, which is what the `where` clause filters out.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fastest to convert to seconds immediately and calculate with integer numbers:

```
SELECT agent
     , to_char(to_timestamp(q) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24:MI') AS quarter_hour
     , least(q + 900, b) - greatest(a, q) AS seconds
FROM   (
   SELECT agent
        , extract(epoch FROM datetimeconnect)::int    AS a
        , extract(epoch FROM datetimedisconnect)::int AS b
   FROM   f_contact
   )  f, generate_series(a / 900 * 900, b, 900) q
ORDER  BY agent DESC, q;
```

Produces the desired result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e6fe563f4291c2b952814126a81ad313)* (with corner cases added to the test case)

#### Key points

- `extract(epoch FROM datetimeconnect)` extracts (quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)) ...

  > the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
- `generate_series()` (the integer variant) generates exactly the number of rows needed, no surplus. The lower bound of each relevant quarter hour, to be precise - the value you display in the result.
- `a / 900 * 900` makes use of [integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) to round down to full quarter hours (multiples of 900). Using this since [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) has no option to truncate to quarter hours
- `least(q + 900, b) - greatest(a, q)` makes sure that start and end are counted correctly, even if both lie within the same quarter hour (as demonstrated in the extended test case in the fiddle).
- `to_timestamp(q) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` because `to_timestamp()` returns `timestamptz`, we want the according `timestamp` at UTC from it.

Aside: `duration` is a functionally dependent value. It's not need for the task and should not be stored in the table redundantly. That's just ballast slowing everything down. It can be computed on the fly cheaply.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()` to generate data series. I would start with generating a series of number, and then `JOIN` it with the original data, to generate 15 minutes slots. An inner query can be used to pre-compute starting and ending bounds.

Consider the following query, that demonstrates the logic to round timestamps to 15 mintes and `JOIN` the table with the series:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM generate_series(0, 99, 1) t(x)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            f.*,
            DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetimeconnect)    
                + DATE_PART('minute', datetimeconnect   )::int / 15 * interval '15 min' connect_15min,
            DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetimedisconnect) 
                + DATE_PART('minute', datetimedisconnect)::int / 15 * interval '15 min' disconnect_15min
        FROM f_contact f
    ) c 
        ON c.disconnect_15min >= c.connect_15min + ((t.x * 15) || ' minute')::interval 
    ORDER BY c.datetimeconnect, t.x;
```

Eg, for `agent = 2011`, this would return:

```
| x   | agent | datetimeconnect          | datetimedisconnect       | duration | connect_15min            | disconnect_15min         |
| --- | ----- | ------------------------ | ------------------------ | -------- | ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 0   | 20011 | 2019-03-11T08:47:40.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:10.000Z | 2550     | 2019-03-11T08:45:00.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:00.000Z |
| 1   | 20011 | 2019-03-11T08:47:40.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:10.000Z | 2550     | 2019-03-11T08:45:00.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:00.000Z |
| 2   | 20011 | 2019-03-11T08:47:40.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:10.000Z | 2550     | 2019-03-11T08:45:00.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:00.000Z |
| 3   | 20011 | 2019-03-11T08:47:40.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:10.000Z | 2550     | 2019-03-11T08:45:00.000Z | 2019-03-11T09:30:00.000Z |
```

---

Now we can do the computation of the duration in the `FROM` clause. The trick is to handle properly the first and the last intervals, using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` (note that `duration` is not used to do the computation):

```
SELECT 
    agent,
    c.connect_15min + ( t.x * 15 || ' minute' )::interval interval_start_15min,

    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (
        LEAST(datetimedisconnect, c.connect_15min + ( (t.x + 1) * 15 || ' minute' )::interval) 
        - GREATEST(datetimeconnect, c.connect_15min + ( t.x * 15 || ' minute' )::interval )
    )) duration
FROM generate_series(0, 99, 1) t(x)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        f.*,
        DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetimeconnect)    
            + DATE_PART('minute', datetimeconnect   )::int / 15 * interval '15 min' connect_15min,
        DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetimedisconnect) 
            + DATE_PART('minute', datetimedisconnect)::int / 15 * interval '15 min' disconnect_15min
    FROM f_contact f
) c 
    ON c.disconnect_15min >= c.connect_15min + ((t.x * 15) || ' minute')::interval 
ORDER BY agent, interval_start_15min;
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5ejRJ2yDNpit5E1yoGA5H/0)** returns:

```
| agent | interval_start_15min     | duration |
| ----- | ------------------------ | -------- |
| 20011 | 2019-03-11T08:45:00.000Z | 740      |
| 20011 | 2019-03-11T09:00:00.000Z | 900      |
| 20011 | 2019-03-11T09:15:00.000Z | 900      |
| 20011 | 2019-03-11T09:30:00.000Z | 10       |
| 20024 | 2019-03-18T12:00:00.000Z | 840      |
| 20024 | 2019-03-18T12:15:00.000Z | 900      |
| 20024 | 2019-03-18T12:30:00.000Z | 900      |
| 20024 | 2019-03-18T12:45:00.000Z | 900      |
| 20024 | 2019-03-18T13:00:00.000Z | 90       |
```